# Xamarin - Wallpaper error: no non-static method "Landroid/app...."

Tags: android, xamarin, wallpaper, wallpapermanager

I want to get and set wallpaper image but it gives to me error in Android 6.0 API 23  but it is working great in Android 9. I also tried `Application.Context` and `this` keyword instead of `ApplicationContext`

My exception;

[Exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPAy3.png)

My codes;

```
WallpaperManager manager = WallpaperManager.GetInstance(ApplicationContext);
            try
            {
                var image = manager.GetWallpaperFile(WallpaperManagerFlags.System);
                Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeFileDescriptor(image.FileDescriptor);
                byte[] bitmapData;
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
                    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "DUVAR KAĞIDI " + ex.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
```

Comment: `GetWallpaperFile` was added in API level 24

Comment: @SushiHangover how can I achieve this under API 24 ?

Comment: You can use `getDrawable` and `getWallpaperInfo` in older APIs

Comment: @SushiHangover I have fixed with this method `PeekDrawable()`  thanks.